# How do I calculate probabilities of outcomes in this experiment?

Tags: probability, terminology

I am interested in knowing the proper terminology and formulas for calculating the probabilities for the following experiment:

1. Twelve volunteers, one born in each month, are randomly arranged.
2. A "psychic" has twelve placards with each month name, and assigns each person a month based on his "senses." The sequence of assignment is unrestricted.
3. The psychic can change assignments, but does not know the number of correct assignments until all are revealed at the end.

What I want to do is calculate what the chances are of correct assignments by chance alone. I do not know the proper terminology to describe this scenario and would like tips on characterizing it. (For example, how would the math change if there were duplicates or omissions of months in the group of volunteers?)

I wrote a simulation program that ran millions of iterations of random assignment and believe the following to be correct:

```
Matches    Percentage
-------    ----------
      0     36.78698%
      1     36.79298%
      2     18.38640%
      3      6.13201%
      4      1.53395%
      5      0.30761%
      6      0.05154%
      7      0.00753%
      8      0.00090%
      9      0.00009%
     10      0.00001%
     12      0.00000%
```

I'd like to know how to describe this scenario correctly, and derive the formulas to arrive at these figures rather than by brute-force in a simulation.

Comment: It generalizes the idea of a [derangement](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=derangement), which is a permutation with no matches.  Deriving the formulas is the subject matter of combinatorics.  For a good modern introduction, see Chapter 1 of Richard Stanley's book [Enumerative Combinatorics](http://math.mit.edu/~rstan/ec/ec1.pdf). There are good approximations in your particular case: have you noticed the pattern in which the initial value is divided by $1$, then that is divided by $2$, then that one by $3$, and so on?

Comment: @whuber Thank you for the tips! Is it correct to say that calculating the zero matches outcome is a derangement while the other outcomes are not?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  But the methods used to count derangements apply to counting the other situations, too.  For instance, the number of permutations yielding exactly three matches corresponds to (a) selecting the three matching months and (b) independently of that, a derangement of the remaining nine months. This easily gives the values $\frac{16019531}{43545600},\frac{1468457}{3991680},\frac{16481}{896
   00},\ldots,0,\frac{1}{479001600}.$